# AngularJS get invalid elements group without form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there a nice way to get a group of elements without using form? My problem is that work with .net mvc and `Html.BeginForm` removes any form inside itself.

```
<fieldset name="user_fieldset">
   <input type="text" ng-model="Firstname" />
   <input type="text" ng-model="Lastname" />
   ...
</fieldset>
<button ng-disabled="user_fieldset.$valid" ng-class="{'disabled' : user_fieldset.$valid}">Next</button>
```

Comment: anyways, you could specify the name tag to form as well as field..whats the problem?

Comment: so i need to check every element by itself or is my example solution even working?

Comment: I think you should use `ng-form` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) directive as attribute.

The example from [AngularJS Hub](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/nestedforms/):

```js
angular.module("mainModule", [])
  .controller("mainController", function ($scope)
  {
    $scope.person = {};
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    label
    {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 120px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    input
    {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    input.ng-invalid
    {
      border: solid red 2px;
    }

    form
    {
      padding: 10px;
    }

    textarea
    {
      width: 250px;
      height: 160px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="mainModule">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <form name="personForm" novalidate>
      <label for="firstNameEdit">First name:</label>
      <input id="firstNameEdit" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="person.firstName" required /><br />
      <label for="lastNameEdit">Last name:</label>
      <input id="lastNameEdit" type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="person.lastName" required /><br />
      <ng-form name="addressForm">
        <label for="addressEdit">Address:</label>
        <input id="addressEdit" type="text" name="address" ng-model="person.address" /><br />
        <label for="zipEdit">ZIP code:</label>
        <input id="zipEdit" type="number" name="zip" ng-model="person.zip" required /><br />
        <label for="cityEdit">City:</label>
        <input id="cityEdit" type="text" name="city" ng-model="person.city" /><br />
        <label for="stateProvinceEdit">State/Province:</label>
        <input id="stateProvinceEdit" type="text" name="stateProvince" ng-model="person.stateProvince" /><br />
        <label for="countryEdit">Country:</label>
        <input id="countryEdit" type="text" name="country" ng-model="person.country" />
      </ng-form>
    </form>
    <br />
    <strong><label for="userDebugText">Person:</label></strong><br />
    <textarea id="userDebugText">{{person | json}}</textarea><br />
    <br />
    <strong>Form validity:</strong><br />
    <ul>
      <li><strong>personForm.$valid =</strong> {{personForm.$valid}}</li>
      <li><strong>personForm.addressForm.$valid =</strong> {{personForm.addressForm.$valid}}</li>
      <li><strong>personForm.firstName.$valid =</strong> {{personForm.firstName.$valid}}</li>
      <li><strong>personForm.lastName.$valid =</strong> {{personForm.lastName.$valid}}</li>
      <li><strong>personForm.addressForm.zip.$valid =</strong> {{personForm.addressForm.zip.$valid}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```